# Inserting an indexed element of array into textbox while in 'edit' mode

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, input

I am making a simple To Do list using AngularJS v1.4.3. [Here is a plunkr of my work so far.](http://plnkr.co/edit/CShZsyzOS8zfL8f9ahin?p=preview)

When the user presses 'Edit', the list item is 'replaced' with an input field, so that they can make amendments to it. However, I can't figure out how to maintain the value of the list item in the edit box. It goes blank. It does however, work as expected when editing a value that the user has edited; ie one that is not part of the array when it's initialised. What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ToDo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <form novalidate>
    <span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="str" placeholder="Enter here">
      <button name="Save" ng-disabled="validated(str)" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </span>
  </form>
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
      <span ng-show="$index !== editedValue">{{entry.name}} 
      </span>
      <!-- When edit button is clicked -->
      <span ng-show="$index === editedValue">
        <input type="text" value="{{entry.name}}" ng-model="updatedValue">
      </span>
      <span>
        <button ng-click="edit(entry)">Edit</button>
        <button ng-click="update(updatedValue)">Update</button>
        <button ng-click="delete(entry)">Delete</button>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <script src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**AngularJS**

```
angular.module('ToDo', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.str = '';
        $scope.editedValue = null;

        $scope.entries = [
            {name: 'Task number 1'}, 
            {name: 'Another task'},
            {name: 'and yet another'}
        ];

        $scope.save = function() { 
            $scope.entries.push( {name: $scope.str} ); 
            $scope.str = '';
        }

        $scope.edit = function(item) {
            var index = $scope.entries.indexOf(item);
            $scope.editedValue = index;
        }

        $scope.update = function(updatedValue) {
            $scope.entries[$scope.editedValue].name = updatedValue;
            $scope.editedValue = null;
        }

        $scope.delete = function(item) {
            var index = $scope.entries.indexOf(item);
            $scope.entries.splice(index, 1);    
        }

        $scope.validated = function(str) {
            return str.length === 0;
        }
    })
;
```

Comment: classic problem of not using a `dot` in `ng-model`, or in other words binding to an object. When you use primitives they lose 2-way binding once they are inside child scopes like `ng-repeat` creates. Not your only issue but is a big one and critical to understand when working with angular

Comment: Going to need to do quite a bit of reconfiguring to get edit to work

Comment: @charlietfl:  Well, I think the issue was: *string in `ng-model` was overriding the string in input's `value` *. This can we fixed by initializing `ng-model` with the string in `value`. See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nD44QTOBcQPlkkGcd2AI?p=preview)

Comment: @charlietfl Please may you provide me with a good example of the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...The list item is 'replaced' with an input field, so that they can make
>   amendments to it. However, I can't figure out how to maintain the
>   value of the list item in the edit box. It goes blank

Thats happening because you are using both `value` and `ng-model` in your input field and former(`value`) is being overridden by latter(`ng-model`)

```
            <input type="text" value="{{entry.name}}" ng-model="updatedValue">
```

You are getting a blank input field because `updatedValue` is empty initially. For the same reason, it seem to work as expected when editing a value that the user has edited(since this time `updatedValue` would have a valid value)

So replace your input field with the following

```
            <input type="text" ng-init="updatedValue =entry.name" value="{{entry.name}}" ng-model="updatedValue">
```

Here's the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nD44QTOBcQPlkkGcd2AI?p=preview)